# Slack Botkit - How to get a message's content from a 'reaction_added' event

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack-api

I'm using the **botkit** framework to respond when a reaction is added to a message but I'm not sure how to extract the message's content when the event is triggered. Below is what I currently have:

```
controller.on('reaction_added',function(bot, event) {

   if (event.reaction == 'x') {
      // bot reply with the message's text
   }
});
```

According to the [Slack API](https://api.slack.com/events/reaction_added), I can only get data like event.item which has the type, channel, and ts of the message. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7):

Figured it out. Given the timestamp and the channel, I was able to manually search for the message in the channel history and extract the data I needed.

```
function getTaskID(channel_id, timestamp, callback) {
  slack.api("channels.history", {
      channel: channel_id,
      latest: timestamp,
      count: 1,
      inclusive: 1
    }, function(err, response) {
      // do something with the response
  });
}
```

Comment: The answer is not really clear, waiting for a better solution.

Comment: which slack package are you using in this example?